# Why does Choice not work inside For loop

Tags: batch-file

```
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,100) DO (
    choice
    echo %ErrorLevel%
    )
```

`%ErrorLevel%` is always `0` no matter what choice you enter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are checking the errorlevel the wrong way.

Variables and commands inside a bracket pair like this...

```
(
  command1
  command2
  command3
)
```

...act like they were run on a single line, like this `command1 & command2 & command3`.

Try this at the command line.

```
choice & echo %errorlevel%
```

If you execute the above command more than once, you will see that the **previous** errorlevel is echoed, **not the current one**.

Or try this on the command line:

```
set x=yes
( echo %x%
  set x=no
  echo %x%
)
```

Your output will be:

```
yes
yes
```

Just as if you'd entered `echo %x% & set x=no& echo %x%`

I like to think of it as the system doesn't have the time to update the variables. (Though it's more accurate to say that the variables only get updated after the entire line is executed.) This is true with all variables, not just the errorlevel.

To make variables in `for` loops work normally you need to `call` an internal label in your batch file (or an external batch file) like this.

```
@echo off
  FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,100) DO call :dostuff %%i
goto :eof

:dostuff
  choice /m "Question #%1"
  echo %ErrorLevel%
```

==================================== **Solution To Question Below**

Alternatively, Microsoft has created a method for accessing the current value of variables inside of a bracket pair, they call it 'Delayed Expansion' because the line of code is interpreted twice.

To activate this mode you use the `setlocal` command with the `enableDelayedExpansion` switch, and access the variables with the ! character like this. FYI `endlocal` turns off the effects.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%i in (1,1,100) do (
  choice /m "Question #%%i"
  echo !ErrorLevel!
)
endlocal
```

As you can see my first example is easier to code, but my second example is easier to read. Whichever method you use will depend upon your needs and re-usability.

The `setlocal` command also has the effect of creating **temporary variables** that die after the `endlocal` command. This means you don't need to delete them when your batch file ends, and reverts any variables you changed during execution back to their original values. This is nice because you don't have to worry about 'stepping on' any preexisting variables.